# File Recursion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a Folder A, which has 100 subfolders, each of those has 3-6 subfolders one of which holds a bunch of txt files. I need to do file recursion to get those. Since I want to give something for people to build off of:

```
import path

rootdir = path(*Folder A location*)
file_list = [f for f in rootdir.glob('**/*') if f.is_file()]

# For absolute paths instead of relative the current dir
file_list = [f for f in rootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()]
```

My goal is to take these `.txt` files containing tables and gather the data from them.

Comment: `each of those has 3-6 subfolders one of which holds a bunch of txt files` What is the identifying criteria for that specific subfolder

Comment: Use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20walk#os.walk). The `os` module is a builtin module, no need to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20walk#os.walk) to recursively find all files ending with `.txt`:

```
import os

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for f in filenames:
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
            print(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
```

Comment: you may want to set `followlinks` to `True` for the `walk()`